# A way to filter data at selection on DB with spring and JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm looking for a simple and practice solution to have the following:

a) filter data on DB on a certain field stored on a Table
(example: if field status is greater than 5 then it would never return)
b) this filter has to work with field with values and null values (for example Date types)
c) I would forgot for the future to remember every time when I write a select or JPA method that has access to this table to add this "filter".

Concrete Example:

I have a Repository for Users where I access and get back the list of all users.
Now I whant to add a condition/filter that say that only users with status 5 have to return. Then I can write ewryting like this:

```
List<User> findAllAndTypeGreatherThan(int status);
```

Now when I came back in a few months and I have to add a new method like

```
List<User> findByName(String name);
```

I musst remember that I have to filter out the types greater than 5 or I forget this. 
I don't whant remeber this..... How can I solve this?

Comment: So is this question specifically about Spring Data JPA?

Comment: Yes and no: at the moment I work on a Spring/JPA project, but I think this would also help for other project. I don't know if spring has a special way to solve this.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add a specific `JPQL` statement to your entity that meets your requirement? Or isn't `JPQL` used with Spring (sorry I don't know much about Spring ;-))?

Comment: You can consider using Hibernate's annotation `@Where(clause="status<>5")` (above the entity class)

Comment: @Darwind: JPQL is used in Spring. Yes I can write it. But If I have more JPQL I have to remember each time to add this criteria/filter.

Comment: @zxcf: it seams that this can be my solution. I have to try it out.

Comment: @java4fun how does the body of your `findAllAndTypeGreaterThan` method look like? Are you using a `NamedQuery` or?

Comment: @Darwind: in spring you have the possibility use Interfaces that extends JPA repository. This gives you the advantage to use the method declaration as Query. [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.2.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.query-methods)

Comment: @java4fun using "magic" isn't always fun :-) Maybe what you want to do isn't good for just letting Spring handle the repositories. Maybe it's better to handle it yourself or find a way to extend the JPA repository? Look further down in the manual you linked to...

Comment: @Darwind: I'm sorry, I'm not sure If I understand what you whant say: You mean to do what described in [1.3](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.2.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations)? I did it. I can add my own query's. But I don't whant to write several times the status filter(findByNameAndStatusGreatherThan(), findByAddressAndStatusGreaterThan(), findByCapAndStatusGreaterThan()). Or I don't have understand you right?

Comment: In 1.3.2 (example 1.17) it's stated how you create a base-class. This baseclass extends `SimpleJpaRepository`. The method `sharedCustomMethod` could be changed to return say a `List<T>` and maybe taking a type `T` as a parameter and making a `createNativeQuery` on the `EntityManager`. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)
I'm sorry if I propose something that may not be easiest solution, but I don't believe your problem can be that easily solved ;-)

Comment: @Darwind: not a problem. It's ok when I receive feed-back and possible solutions :) then I can try and see what's the best way for me :) Ok i will try you're propose.

Comment: @java4fun I'll be happy to supply you with a pseudo example of how it could look like if you want it ;-)

Comment: @Darwind I tank you for you're response. At the end I stopped to search a solution. Because how do you say: I don't believe my problem can be that easily solved :) But I tank you for you're patience. I would give you a +1 for you're response and effort.